# Issue passing table row data to bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've gone through several examples but for some reason I'm unable to get data from my table to pass to my modal. I could use some expert guidance.

Table row is dynamically populated and looks like this:

```
    <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="cursor: pointer" data-id="<?php echo $site_info['site_id']; ?>">
        <td><?php echo $site_info['site_id']; ?></td>
        ...
```

The modal and JS are below:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:55%;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Site Information</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="siteDetails">asdf</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {

            var getId = $(event.relatedTarget).data('id');
            $("#siteDetails").html('Selected: ' + getId);   

        });

    }); 


</script>
```

How can I make sure that the #siteDetails div gets updated?

Thanks!

Comment: I tested your code and it is working fine. What are you getting in your `siteDetails` div after you show the modal?

Comment: The modal launches but I still get the "asdf" dummy text.

Comment: do you get any console errors??

Comment: I got: "jquery.app.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).getNiceScroll is not a function", "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" and "jquery.dataTables.min.js:41 Uncaught TypeError: a.charAt is not a function"

Comment: Yes, thats the problem since that jquery is breaking its effecting your scripts. In the scense your script is never triggered. You can place a alert and check.. So if you clear the above errors then it will fix the issues.

Comment: Thank you! I reordered js scripts to get them to load before being called and that seemed to fix it for me.

Comment: great!!! simple as that.